# About the function $ f(a) = \int \limits_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln y}{e^{ay} + 1} \ dy $

Tags: calculus

We define the following function $$ f(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln y}{e^{ay} + 1} \ dy $$

and $$ f(r) = f'(r') = 0 $$ find $$ \int_r^{r'} f(a) \ da $$

Comment: Is $\;r'\;$ only a symbol for a number? Why then put it together with $\;f'\;$ which, apparently, is the symbol used for the derivative? Or is there something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I'll spare the derivation to get to the point.  I get for $f(a)$

$$f(a) = -\frac{\log (2) (2 \log (a)+\log (2))}{2 a}$$

so that $f(r)=0$ when $r=1/\sqrt{2}$.  Also,

$$f'(a) = \frac{\log (2) (2 \log (a)-2+\log (2))}{2 a^2}$$

so that $f'(r') = 0$ when $r'=e/\sqrt{2}$.  Then the integral is

$$\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^{e/\sqrt{2}} da \, f(a) = \left [-\frac{1}{2} \log (2) \log (a) \log (2 a)\right]_{1/\sqrt{2}}^{e/\sqrt{2}} = -\frac{1}{2} \log (2) [1+\log{(2)}]$$

Comment: The condition appears to be $f'(r')=0$ though i.e. $r'=\frac{e\sqrt{2}}{2}$ (by the way, I think you mean $r=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$)

Comment: @L.F.: Oh...my bad.  I will fix.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, we first express $f(a)$ in terms of $f(1)$ .

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(a) & =\frac{1}{a} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(\frac{u}{a}\right)}{e^u+1} d u \\
& =\frac{1}{a}\left(f(1)-\ln a \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^u+1} d u\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{a}(f(1)-\ln a \ln 2)
\end{aligned}
$$
For evaluating $f(1)$, we consider the parametrised integral in $b$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
I(b) & =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{b-1}}{e^x+1} d x \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{b-1}}{e^x+1} d x \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} x^{b-1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n e^{-n x} d x \\
& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \int_0^{\infty} x^{b-1} e^{-(n+1) x} d x \\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \frac{\Gamma(b)}{n^b}\\&= \Gamma(b) \eta(b)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\Gamma(.)$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and $\eta(.)$ is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function).

Now differentiating $I(b)$ w.r.t. $b$ at $b=1$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(1)&=I^{\prime}(1) \\& =\Gamma(1) \eta^{\prime}(1)+\Gamma^{\prime}(1) \eta(1) \\
& =\eta^{\prime}(1)-\gamma \ln 2 \\
& =\gamma \ln 2-\frac{1}{2} \ln ^2 2-\gamma \ln 2 \\
& =-\frac{1}{2} \ln ^2 2
\end{aligned}
$$
Plugging back gives our integral$$
\boxed{f(a)=-\frac{\ln 2}{2 a}(\ln 2+2 \ln a)}
$$
Noting that
$$f(r)=0 \Leftrightarrow r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \textrm{   and } f^{\prime}\left(r^{\prime}\right)=\frac{\ln 2}{2 r^{\prime 2}}\left(\ln 2+2 \ln r^{\prime}-2\right)=0 \Leftrightarrow r^{\prime}=\frac{e}{\sqrt{2}} $$
Hence
$$
\int_r^{r^{\prime}} f(a) d a =-\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{\frac{e}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{\ln 2}{2 a}(\ln 2+2 \ln a) d a =\boxed{-\frac{\ln 2}{2}}
$$